# Web scrapping com R, java ou html?

Tags: r

Como eu faço para extrair a tabela de dados da seguinte página:http://www.ons.org.br/resultados_operacao/boletim_semanal/2016_12_16/ena.htm

Comment: Recomendo que 1. Você escolha entre R e java baseado na sua experiência e no que você pretende fazer com as informações, são linguagens muito diferentes. 2. Tente fazer por sua conta, e se não conseguir poste aqui a sua tentativa para que alguém te ajude a entender o que deu errado.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse rpositório https://github.com/dfalbel/ons tem códigos de webscrapping de diversas partes do site da ons

Comment: se optar por java (já que a pergunta é ampla), use [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dá uma olhada no pacote [`rvest`](https://github.com/hadley/rvest).

A página que você quer foi realmente construída usando péssimas práticas, o que dificulta um pouco o trabalho. Analisando o código da página, é possível descobrir que o conteúdo de fato se encontra no endereço http://www.ons.org.br/resultados_operacao/boletim_semanal/2016_12_16/ena_arquivos/sheet001.htm

Então, o código a seguir captura o conteúdo da página:

```
library(rvest)
tb = read_html("http://www.ons.org.br/resultados_operacao/boletim_semanal/2016_12_16/ena_arquivos/sheet001.htm") %>% 
  html_node("table") %>% 
  html_table(fill = TRUE)
```

Aí você usa subsetting pra pegar só o que interessa, e põe uns nomes adequados nas colunas.

```
tb = tb[6:9, 2:4]
colnames(tb) = c("Região", "M/W Médios", "% MLT")
```